# Java- Output not printing

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedimage, javax.imageio, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm trying to convert an image file to Base64 string using BufferedImage class. Even though the code is not giving any compilation/run time errors the output is not getting printed in the console.

Eclipse IDE code:

```
public class BufferImage {

public static void main(String args[]) {
try 
{
    BufferedImage img = null;
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg")); // eventually C:\\ImageTest\\pic2.jpg
    String image_string = encodeToString(img, "string");
    System.out.println(image_string);
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static String encodeToString(BufferedImage image, String type) 
{
    String base64String = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
    ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);
    byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    base64String = encoder.encode(imageBytes);
    bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return base64String;
    }
}
```

How to overcome this?

Comment: I _really_ wonder why you think that `"string"` is a valid format name. Use `"jpg"` instead ("bmp", "png" or whatever your picture is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in `ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);`. In your case type is `"String"`, but that is most likely not a valid format. To see all the formats at your disposal execute `ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames()`.

If you can use Apache Commons, I suggest you try the following to encode your file to Base64: (`fileImage` is of type `File`):

```
byte[] imageBytes = Base64.encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(fileImage)); 
String base64String = new String(imageBytes);
```